# How do I install modules such as (pandas/ openpyxl)

Tags: python, pycharm

Okay so I have just started to learn python. I use pycharm to currently write the code. I just dont understand how I install modules. For example I wish to load in excel files. I have seen that either pandas or openpyxl can be used, but I dont get how I get access to these modules. All videos I have seen online just type either install openpyxl or pip install pandas. 'install' does not come up as a valid function on my window. Other functions come up highlighted before I complete them and install seems to be like its not recognized and once executed I get a syntax error for install. Do I have to download these modules before installing?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pip install <package>
```

needs to be written in terminal, not in code window. In the bottom left corner you have "terminal" button, press it, and in new window type pip install whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot that makes everything make sense. Much appreciated such a simple fix for the headache its caused me.